# Remove nav menu from login page

Tags: angularjs

Have base html admin_layout.html where i wrote this:

```
<body>
    <div ng-include="'/static/partials/admin_navigation.html'"></div>
    <div ng-view></div>
```

Interested to know how may remove admin navigation from login page?

Tryed to set variable hide_menu in **LoginCtrl** and hide it with ng-if="hide_menu", but this doesn`t work for me. It hide menu in all admin panel.

UPD: Fixed it adding to navigation div Menu controller. Or better create menu directive?

**UPD2:**

Added in **admin_app.js**:

```
adminApp.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.location = $location;
});
```

and in **admin_layout.html**:

```
<nav ng-include="'/static/partials/admin_navigation.html'" ng-if="location.path() !== '/admin/login'"></nav>
```

Now everything work fine

Comment: And you want to hide it only on the login page?

Comment: have you tried using ngshow or nghide?

Comment: @Shomz no i wanna remove it, that people who not logged it will not see it at all.

Comment: @AlexChoroshin Tryed, but it same as ng-if :(

Comment: @Luam Then you should probably create a login variable and bind the ng-if to it (`ng-if="loggedIn"`)

Comment: @Shomz but how i can make it globally? because when i create it just in LoginCtrl navigation not showing in another pages of admin. Maybe its null in another ctrls..

Comment: If nothing else, you can use the rootScope.

Comment: fixed it by adding controller to the nav tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed problem using code that i wrote in UPD2 of my question

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand it right now, your Problem is that the value of "hide_menu" does not depend on the route you're currently in.

So i would suggest you set the value in the controller according to the page you are currently displaying. You could for example listen for the $routeChangeSuccess event and read out the $route.current object accordingly.

If you need more specific help, please provide a plunkr!

Comment: i just looking for something similar to logic like in normal template engines where you can just in one view function define variable that you will futher check in template.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can work it with ng-show or ng-hide.
like for those URL's you dont want to have the nav bar you can hide iot using ng-hide i.e.
URL for which you wants to hide nav bar -http://********.com/view1.html

```
<div ng-include="'/static/partials/admin_navigation.html'" ng-hide="URL == '/view1.html'"></div>
```

Comment: i don`t wanna hide it i whant delete it from DOM at all

Comment: you can remove it from the DOm using element.remove() function and it would remove the elemnets from the DOM

Comment: This is old, but ng-if removes it completely from the DOM.