# Want to separate between login page to the other pages application angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to separate between the login page to the others pages of the application.

Because I use angularjs, I put a menu bar and `<ng-view>` that pages are display in.

but I want that in the login page the menu bar wont exist , and after it within the application, that menu bar will appear and the `<ng-view>` also.

How can I add after the login the `<ng-view>` directive?

Answer (score 0):

Let ng-view stay and manipulate the appearance of the header from the controller (hide it when the route is login and show when it's not). You can comunicate between the header controller and the login controller via a shared service or by firing an event.

Comment: See this post for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141522/remove-nav-menu-from-login-page